# Maven 3 Jenkins Plugin - "Build Failure" for Hello World example

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

I am using Jenkins/Maven for the first time and am following these two tutorials together to write a Jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial and http://cleantestcode.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/how-to-write-a-jenkins-plugin-part-1/.

So far, these are the commands/data I've entered at the prompt on Windows:

1. mvn hpi:create -Pjenkins
2. enter "org.jenkins-ci.tools" as the groupId
3. enter "hello_world" as the artifactId
4. cd hello_world
5. mvn install

The result of step 5 is "BUILD FAILURE" with this output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test           (default-test) on project hello_world: There are test failures. [ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\$HOME\hello_world\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have tried "mvn install -DskipTests" instead, but this way (I'm not sure how to phrase it) the command prompt never appears again and I am unable to enter any more commands.

My questions are these:

1. I have not modified any of the files generated by "mvn hpi:create -Pjenkins" so what could cause the default tests to fail?
2. Without the "-Pjenkins" flag, the command "mvn hpi:create" resulted in a build failure as well. What was the effect of adding the "-Pjenkins" flag?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

[Edit] Here are the contents of the Surefire reports:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: InjectedTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.697 sec <<< FAILURE!
org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite(org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.FailedTest)  Time elapsed: 0.012 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.entrySet(OrderRetainingMap.java:77)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.<init>(OrderRetainingMap.java:36)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldsFor(FieldDictionary.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:127)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:149)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:108)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:898)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:887)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:860)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:179)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:2656)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setNoUsageStatistics(Jenkins.java:988)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.setUp(HudsonTestCase.java:320)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite.setUp(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:133)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.GroupedTest.run(GroupedTest.java:49)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
testCliSanity(org.jvnet.hudson.test.PluginAutomaticTestBuilder$CliSanityTest)  Time elapsed: 0.027 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: second instance
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:758)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.newHudson(HudsonTestCase.java:469)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.setUp(HudsonTestCase.java:312)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.runBare(HudsonTestCase.java:290)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
```

Comment: what does the surefire report contain in `C:\$HOME\hello_world\target\surefire-reports`

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn I have added the report contents. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to skip tests, change 5th command into:
5. mvn install -DskipTests

Comment: I tried that and was able to build successfully. Can you explain why skipping the tests affected the build? @jussuper

Comment: i don't know what you have in your tests, but those errors may be coused be version of java

Comment: yes,  I think the default Initialized jdk version should be 1.6 ,try to remove old jdk ,and replace with JDK 1.7 or higher ,hope this helps.